# Mysql “memory usage” keeps increasing

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have 32core CPU 204GB RAM Mysql 5.6 server, hosted on GCP VM.
I keep getting RAM high usage issues.
I have around 200+ tables, most of which are Innodb.
At any time, i see arnd 1k+ active connections to my database and most of which are sleep connections, My application runs on ROR, cant skip sleep connections

Here is my.cnf details

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet              = 512M
max_connect_errors              = 1000000
skip_external_locking
skip_name_resolve
sql_mode                        = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
user                            = mysql
max_binlog_size         = 500M
expire_logs_days                = 14
log_slave_updates               = TRUE
master_info_repository          = TABLE
binlog_format                   = ROW

# InnoDB Settings
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 9  
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 160G 
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
innodb_stats_on_metadata        = 0

innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64

# MyISAM Settings
query_cache_limit               = 4M   
query_cache_size                = 48M  
query_cache_type                = 1    

key_buffer_size                 = 48M  

low_priority_updates            = 1
concurrent_insert               = 2

# Connection Settings
max_connections                 = 5000 

back_log                        = 512
thread_cache_size               = 100
thread_stack                    = 192K

interactive_timeout             = 180
wait_timeout                    = 180

# Buffer Settings
join_buffer_size                = 4M  
read_buffer_size                = 3M  
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 4M  
sort_buffer_size                = 4M  

# Table Settings
table_definition_cache          = 10000
table_open_cache                = 20000
open_files_limit                = 60000

max_heap_table_size             = 256M
tmp_table_size                  = 512M

# Search Settings
ft_min_word_len                 = 3     # Minimum length of words to be indexed for search results

symbolic-links                  = 0
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: How high is "high ram usage"?

Comment: @Girisha Can you provide any of the information requested?